# How to use str.get_dummies with prefix in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`pd.get_dummies()` supports `prefix` ([ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)).

How to use `prefix` with the following?

```
dummies = data_df['genres_names'].str.get_dummies()
```

`get_dummies(prefix='genre')` throws an error:

```
TypeError: get_dummies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefix'
```

Comment: you looking for pd.get_dummies

Answer (score 6):

one way to achieve that is `add_prefix`

```
data_df['genres_names'].str.get_dummies().add_prefix('something')
```